# Rendering data in handlebars using express framework

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

Hello I am working in Express Framework, I am using handlebars to render the data from my mysql table. While trying to render the data using below code,instead of rendering value it displaying [object object]. I posted my code below.

**index.js:**

```
 var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM requestor_auth WHERE question_id = ? AND answer = ? AND app_key = ?  LIMIT 1', [data.qid, data.ansvalue, data.appid], function(err,rows)
    {

        if(err) {
            console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );
            res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            res.render('requestform',{page_title:"Edit Customers - Node.js",data:rows});
          }
```

**requestform.hbs:**

```
    <div class="addressto">
              <h4>To,</h4>
                <br>
                  <span style="font-size:18px;margin-left:10px;">The Collector Of</span>
                  <input type="text" value="{{data}}" class="line" class="text-line" style="margin-left:35px;"><br>

    </div>
```

The value in the form input displaying as [object object]. I tried as data.key_value to render the data but it is not displaying the value. 
Please give me a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the result of Mysql response is array so it should be:

```
 var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM requestor_auth WHERE question_id = ? AND answer = ? AND app_key = ?  LIMIT 1', [data.qid, data.ansvalue, data.appid], function(err,rows) {

        if(err) {
            console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );
            res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            res.render('requestform',{page_title:"Edit Customers - Node.js",data:rows[0]});
          }
```

If there's a same error you should `console.log()` your result to check the value.

Comment: Great, @ Burdy data is displaying in the form. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The rows argument in your callback function is by a select query always an array of objects. With handlebars you should be able to do the following:

```
<div class="addressto">
    <h4>To,</h4>
    <br>
    <span style="font-size:18px;margin-left:10px;">The Collector Of</span>
    <input type="text" value="{{data[0].answer}}" class="line text-line" style="margin-left:35px;">
    <br>
</div>
```

Also multiple class names can be in one class attribute.

Comment: Hi Dirk, I have tried your code, but it is throwing parse error.Expecting ID, STRING, BOOLEAN, etc